# How to create animation with floating circles and text inside?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create bubble`s animation like [this](http://prntscr.com/nxxs5s).

I use particles.js, but there is no way to insert text inside the circle. The bubbles must smoothly move like [here](http://maxborsu.bget.ru/rustrends).

Initialization particles.js

```js
function runParticles(id) {

  particlesJS(id, {

    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 1,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 40
        }
      },
      "color": {
        "value": "#ffffff"
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": "image",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
        "polygon": {
          "nb_sides": 1
        },
        "image": {
          "src": pref + "/bubble.png"
        }
      },
      "opacity": {
        "value": 1,
        "random": false,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 1,
          "opacity_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "size": {
        "value": 155,
        "random": true,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 80,
          "size_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "line_linked": {
        "enable": true,
        "distance": 400,
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "opacity": 1,
        "width": 0
      },
      "move": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 3,
        "direction": "none",
        "random": false,
        "straight": false,
        "out_mode": "bounce",
        "bounce": true,
        "attract": {
          "enable": false,
          "rotateX": 100,
          "rotateY": 100
        }
      }
    },
    "interactivity": {
      "detect_on": "canvas",
      "events": {
        "onhover": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "grab"
        },
        "onclick": {
          "enable": false,
          "mode": "repulse"
        },
        "resize": true
      },
      "modes": {
        "grab": {
          "distance": 40,
          "line_linked": {
            "opacity": 1
          }
        },
        "bubble": {
          "distance": 400,
          "size": 40,
          "duration": 2,
          "opacity": 1,
          "speed": 3
        },
        "repulse": {
          "distance": 60,
          "duration": 0.4
        },
        "push": {
          "particles_nb": 4
        },
        "remove": {
          "particles_nb": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
  });
}


runParticles('particles-js');
```

When a user clicks on a bubble, he should be redirected to another page.

How to put some text inside moving bubble and create a link in order to a user will be redirected to another page?

Thanks in advance for your help:)

Comment: Can you at least put a the code you're working on?

Comment: Of course, https://pastebin.com/By4uAj0v

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like particel.js is only for creating particles which dont' have textures by nature. Maybe [threejs](https://threejs.org) works better for that